# Volunteer Web Application to Connect People

Tags: web-development, javascript, users, registration, table

Apologies if this is in the wrong place, please move or suggest a move if appropriate.

I have some free time on my hands for the foreseeable future. In order to help people in the current climate I was considering creating a web application to connect people that need help and people that are able to offer help.

I'm thinking of a simple responsive, web based application asking users if they are 'Seeking Help' or 'Offering Help'. Based on the selection the following would happen;

**Seeking Help**

- table of volunteers is displayed
- volunteers table includes name, location (postcode), email, phone, service(s) offered (dropdown list)
- table is filterable (maybe using js datatables plugin or similar?)

**Offering Help**

- a signup form asking for name, location, email, phone, service(s) offered
- a consent checkbox requiring users to agree their details will be made public

**Notes**

- there would be no messaging service, users would have to contact volunteers via phone / email
- volunteers would have to agree that that their personal details would be viewable by the public
- users would have the ability to remove their details at any stage
- would be developed using html, css, js, php, mysql

Ideally I'd like to use Google Maps to offers users the ability to filter by location, but I think this is an enhanced feature I could be working on in the background.

Can anyone see any issues with this web application idea, either from a usability, legal or privacy angle?
Can anyone suggest any (easy to develop) feature that would improve the service?

This is something that I'm looking to develop quite quickly. I have limited time and skills.

I'm open to suggestions / links to existing similar applications or repos would be a great help!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, however such open ended questions are not a good match for this site.

Comment: Using your skills to connect volunteers is an admirable goal. Sorry it's not a good fit with the format of this site. You can list your contact info in your bio and perhaps others that see this will get in touch.